# AS3 How to add multiple user input in a textfield

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, text, input

I have a MovieClip called (ps1)  with input textfields inside i.e.( Name, Address, Phone Number... etc)

and I also have a textfield box called (newText) that will receive the user input from the input textfields.

1.how can I save multiple user inputs to newText?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like that:

```
Name.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, OnUpdate);
Address.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, OnUpdate);
Phone.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, OnUpdate);

function OnUpdate(e:Event):void {
    newText.text = "Name: " + Name.text + " Adress: " + Address.text + " Phone: " + Phone.text;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but im not trying to add users, I'm just trying to have ps1 text equal newText, but set it up in a way that every time a user enters the information into the ps1 input text, that a newText textfield retrieves that information

Comment: @fi500 I changed my answer.

Comment: Thank you I'm going to try this out, makes so much sense... I've just been looking at code to long to think straight